# "Fault: Connection closed after GOAWAY. HTTP/2 error code: NO_ERROR, debug data: session_timed_out" when sending request to Google Ads API

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I am using [google-ads-java](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-java) library to fetch campaigns from my Google Ads account follow this [Google Ads API tutorial](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/get-started/make-first-call?hl=en). 
Everything is smooth with my `ads.properties` setting (clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken, developerToken, loginCustomerId)

But when it runs, it doesn't output anything then after a while, it shows an error:

```
c.g.ads.googleads.lib.request.summary    : FAILURE REQUEST SUMMARY. Method: google.ads.googleads.v15.services.GoogleAdsService/SearchStream, Endpoint: googleads.googleapis.com:443, CustomerID: {my_ad_manager_id}, RequestID: null, ResponseCode: UNAVAILABLE, Fault: Connection closed after GOAWAY. HTTP/2 error code: NO_ERROR, debug data: session_timed_out.
c.g.ads.googleads.lib.request.detail     : FAILURE REQUEST DETAIL.

Request
-------
MethodName: google.ads.googleads.v15.services.GoogleAdsService/SearchStream
Endpoint: googleads.googleapis.com:443
Headers: {developer-token=REDACTED, login-customer-id={my_ad_manager_id}, x-goog-api-client=gl-java/19.0.2 gccl/28.0.0 gapic/28.0.0 gax/2.32.0 grpc/1.56.1}
Body: customer_id: "{my_ad_account_id}"
query: "SELECT campaign.id, campaign.name FROM campaign ORDER BY campaign.id"

Response
--------
Headers: null
Body: null
Failure message: null
Status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Connection closed after GOAWAY. HTTP/2 error code: NO_ERROR, debug data: session_timed_out, cause=null}.
```

No further info at my local.
When I check the **Google Cloud APIs & Services Dashboard**, it shows all the requests got **403 error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.

**Firstly**, google-ads-java client can't get the response from Google API servers because of my company's security. The SSL cert has been changed to Netskope self-cert. Tested on my personal computer and everything is fine. When I try with `curl`, the error is clear.

```
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.ads.googleads.v15.errors.GoogleAdsFailure",
"errors": [
    {
        "errorCode": {
            "authorizationError": "DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED"
        },
        "message": "The developer token is only approved for use with test accounts. To access non-test accounts, apply for Basic or Standard access."
    }
]
```

I need to create a new Test Ad Manager account and create a Test Client Ad account inside follow this guide: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/best-practices/test-accounts

**Secondly**, I can't create a Test Client Ad account via Google Ads GUI, it doesn't allow us to create with error (same as in: https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/249148718/can-t-create-a-test-client-account?hl=en)

```
To create new accounts, link an existing account
This needs to be a Google Ads account that
* has spent more than $1,000
* has a history of policy compliance
```

Fortunately, we can create a Test Client Ad account via API with `curl` by this guide: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/examples#creating_accounts

```
curl --location 'https://googleads.googleapis.com/v15/customers/{Your_test_ad_manager_customer_id}:createCustomerClient' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'developer-token: {Your_test_developer_token}' \
--header 'login-customer-id: {Your_test_ad_manager_customer_id}' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {Your_OAuth2_access_token}' \
--data '{
    "customerClient": {
        "descriptiveName": "My Test Client",
        "currencyCode": "JPY",
        "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo"
    }
}'
```